# How to find all DataSources binding to an application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to use spring-boot, spring-cloud to get all DataSources binded to the cloud foundry application.
Is there a way to get the list?
If I can get service names, I can also use

```
AbstractCloudConfig.connectionFactory().dataSource(serviceId)
```

to create the DataSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to enumerate over the list of database services and get a `DataSource` for each one:

```
Cloud cloud = abstractCloudConfig.cloud();
List<ServiceInfo> serviceInfos = cloud.getServiceInfos(DataSource.class);
List<DataSource> dataSources = new ArrayList<>();
for (ServiceInfo serviceInfo : serviceInfos) {
    dataSources.add(cloud.getServiceConnector(serviceInfo.getId, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataSources configuration is set in the container environment inside 'VCAP_SERVICES' variable in Cloud Foundry. System.getenv('VCAP_SERVICES') should list all the datasources in your case.

Refer to:
https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES